# How do I use .htaccess to disable mod_security for only one section of a site?

Tags: .htaccess

I have researched and am pretty sure I need to disable mod_security to allow my jquery to use php to load images. My work is sitting along side a joomla site with the joomla sitting in the root directory and mine in www.example.com/mysite/... am I able to use .htaccess to disable mod_security for only my sub directory and leave the joomla section untouched?

Comment: It seems that this was previously answered. [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-to-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file