# Can't save Javascript in WordPress text widget

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget, aweber

I'm trying to embed an AWeber sign-up form into my primary sidebar using javascript and the text widget. However, when I click save the progress wheel spins forever. When I refresh the page after a lengthly amount of time the code is gone. So the real problem is that the save is not working when my code is pasted in there. Saving works almost instantly with text and html so I'm assuming the javascript is what's holding everything up. I've never had a problem with this before. It used to save without any problem. Here is the code I'm trying to save.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/78/2041064078.js"></script>
```

I even upgraded WordPress to the latest version (3.5.2) from 3.4.1 but am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Who is your web host? This might be caused by mod_security

Comment: GoDaddy is hosting this client's site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org) isn't allowing you to post that. You might be able to turn it off in .htaccess (see here: [How can I disable mod_security in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-to-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file)).

You also may be able to trick it by posting something slightly different like, say, `<div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/78/2041064078.js"></script>`.

Alternatively, you can just hard code it directly into the template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to do that is to create a new widget. It's quite easy. The basic structure is something like this:

```
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget{

function MyWidget() {
    // Instantiate the parent object
    parent::__construct( false, 'name', array('description'=>'the description', 'classname'=>'class-name') );
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract($args);

    echo $before_widget;
    echo '<h3>title</h3>';

            //do some logic here

    echo $after_widget;
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    // Save widget options
}

function form( $instance ) {
    // Output admin widget options form
}
}

function my_init_widgets() {
    register_widget('MyWidget');
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_nit_widgets' );
```

That's all.
Maybe then you should define some custom sidebar, for example:

```
//init sidebar
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sidebars_init' );

function sidebars_init(){
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'id' => 'default-sidebar',
        'name' => __( 'Default sidebar' ),
        'description' => __( "Generic sidebar" ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    )
);
```

If you define your own widgets, you can then add whatever javascript you want.