# Why does this htaccess regex fail with 3 or more periods?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Why does this RegEx fail?

**The goal is to rewrite:**

`http://example.com/Almost-Anything-Here/381`
--> `/lv.php?id=381&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Note that I am ignoring the text in the URL and just trying to get the number (in this example, 381), which I pass to `lv.php`.

**Here is the rule:**

`RewriteRule  ^[/]?[A-Za-z0-9\-_(\.)*]+/([0-9]+)$    /lv.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

It works if there are 0, 1 or 2 periods but fails (with an HTTP 500) for 3 or more periods. Why?! I tried a few ways of escaping/capturing the period in the regex but no luck.

**Example Test URLs:**

- works: `http://example.com/Great/381`
- works: `http://example.com/Great./381`
- works: `http://example.com/Great../381`
- fails: `http://example.com/Great.../381`

**UPDATE Here is the error msg from the server log, clearly a regex problem, still not sure why...**

`Access denied with code 500. Pattern match "\\\\.\\\\.\\\\./" at REQUEST_URI. [msg "Bogus Path denied"] [hostname "www.example.com"] [uri "/Great.../381"]`

Comment: Can you check the logs for the HTTP 500?

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird, that provided a huge clue....

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I don't think you have to escape the dot `\.` in the character class.

Comment: no problem using `xampp`, do you have `RewriteBase /` in your htaccess

Comment: @ewwink thanks for the idea; I added that, no change unfortunately. The error in the log seems to imply that it is in some kind of recursive loop but I am not sure what or how.

Comment: What if you use `RewriteRule ^.*/([0-9]+)/?$ /lv.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` instead?

Comment: Instead of using a complax regex pattern can't you just use `^.+/([0-9]+)$` ?

Comment: @starkeen great idea, thank you... but still fails with 3 periods! what do you make of the error message in the server log? I think that is the clue to solve this, though I don't know exactly why.

Comment: @revo tried adding the QSA, too. no change :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure your Apache web server has [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) installed and contains a security configuration like this:

```
#generic bogus path sigs
SecRule REQUEST_URI "\.\.\./" "id:300006,rev:1,severity:2,msg:'Bogus Path denied'"
```

There are some [ways to turn it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-can-i-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file), but usually, mod_security is implemented for a reason.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this was one of the default rules in ModSecurity 2.x. However, I could not find it in the rules for 3.x - but maybe I was looking at the wrong spot.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, looks very likely that this is the culprit! This begs the question, why is that rule in mod_security and do I need to keep it there? Can I just kill it from the mod_security config?

Comment: @Eric I cannot give a definitive answer here but arguably the SecRule is more a sanity check than a real security protection. It might be worth to ask on webmasters.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Eric Arguably, this rule should be removed if it gets in your way. I found here an incident where this rule blocked vbulletion users: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/366277-modsec2-blocking-vbulletin-suite and here is a description of the rule and it's rationale: https://wiki.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/WAF_340008 `There is no such valid path in any operating system`

Comment: Thank you for your help and research! Accepted your answer as best. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to chuckle when I saw that rule: "Let's by all means preserve the possibility of directory traversal attacks but we need to block access to paths that can't exist and therefore couldn't harm us if we let them pass!"